# No page refresh on form submission (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, forms, page-refresh

**Is there a way in laravel that will not allow the website to refresh on form submission ?**

Answer (score 1):

**STEP1:**

> Include Jquery CDN

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
               integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
               crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

**STEP2:**

> Create controller function

```
public function FUNCTION_NAME(Request $request){
  $input = $request->all();
  $field_1 =trim($input['field1']);
  $field_2 =trim($input['field2']);
  $field_3 =trim($input['field3']);
  $success=array();

  if((!empty($field_1) || !empty($field_2) && !empty($field_3)){
        $ret = DB::table('TBL_NAME')->insert([
        'field_1' => $field_1,
        'field_2' => $field_2,
        'field_3' => $field_3,
        ]);

        $success = array('success'=>1,'msg'=>'Values successfully inserted!');
      }
    } else{
    $success = array('success'=>2,'msg'=>'Mandatory fields missing');
  }

    return json_encode($success); exit();
}
```

**STEP3:**

> Add ajax function in blade template

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.saveValues').click(function() {
        var field1 = $('#field1').val();
        var field2 = $('#field2').val();
        var field3 = $('#field3').val();
        if (field1 != '' && field2 != '' && || field3 != '') {
          $('.successmsg').html('');
          $('.successmsg').removeAttr('style');
          $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo e(url("/YOUR_ROUTE")); ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            'headers': {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
            },
            data: {
              field_1: field1,
              field_2: field2,
              field_3: field3
            },
            success: function(response) {
              var res = JSON.parse(response); // alert(res.success);
              if (res.success == true) {
                $('.successmsg').html('Values updated!').show();
                setTimeout(function() {
                  $('#updatesubmodel').modal('hide');
                }, 2000);
              } else {
                $('.successmsg').html(res.msg).show();
              }
            }
          });
        } else {
          $('.successmsg').html('Required fields are missing.').show();
        }
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create JS function that will send the request for you, and leave the user on the page. Attach it to the submit button, and use event.preventDefault(), to stop the redirect.

Comment: Ok that means its impossible in laravel only. Thank you vert much

Comment: "Laravel only" means PHP execution, which always redirects to form target url in order to process your submission, and target script will show results or redirect browser to another page.